# Animation that produces object change eg curtain drawstring torus

Tags: animation

I am making my first delicate steps into animation by creating a pair of curtains, via a plane, and using animation of a torus scaling down to move the cloth via the Collision property.

I wanted to do a pair and to try and make the pair look natural in that they might be slightly different with different torus size and positioning.

So I did 50 frames of a left and right curtain with their own toruses applied.

the animation only worked correctly for one of these. The second one scaled down at a much higher rate than the 50 frames suggested and created one pair of very distorted curtains and a very small torus, way smaller than the torus size I had saved at 50 frames.

I have 2 questions and would like help with both:

1. Is there any reason why 2 animations would create an anomaly in one of them?
2. In this instance, I only want to use the result of the animation ie the affected curtain and torus. Can I save these as objects that are fixed with the folds as result of the animation? I guess this is a simple "how do I save and use the animation result".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn’t enough information to be able to say why your two animations are behaving differently - most likely there is a significant difference such as additional keyframes or differences in geometry (such as negative scale - try ‘Apply Scale’ or check the direction of your normals).

However, to ‘fix’ the state of the cloth simulation into your mesh (so it becomes a static mesh again) you simply play the simulation to the point you want and then in the Modifiers panel click ‘Apply’ on the Cloth modifier. This will apply the current state of the simulation to the mesh and it will no longer be simulated.